# Filter for AC line coupling with audio signal source

Tags: ac, audio, filter, coupling, cutoff-frequency

I need a sharp notch filter (higher order) for the 50-60 Hz band, to be placed between AC 220/125 V power line and an audio source (not necessarily amplified), such that the input signal from the audio source is passed into the power line.

For my purpose it is acceptable to have transmitted an audio band with the 50-60 Hz cutoff. I actually need to transmit frequencies in the audible range, possibly including the subrange < 50 Hz beside the subrange > 60 Hz.

The application would be for a brain therapy project, to be used within the user's own domestic power line, based on experimental results I verified. The project, when working as expected, will be open sourced for public health.

Using the power line as a transmission medium is chosen in order to make it easily available on every domestic environment, cheap and widespread.

What kind of filter is suitable for such an application? It could actually be inspired from a coupling circuit for PLC, with the difference it doesn't need to be bidirectional (does not need to receive any signal from the power line) and should work with lower frequencies.

Comment: You want to transfer analog audio, on mains wiring that also carries power? Within a home, or from power company to all homes?

Comment: There are plenty of wireless means of audio transmission that are reliable, licensed throughout large portions of the world, and have common ICs available (e.g. Bluetooth) without potentially relying on a filter as a single point of failure to prevent AC mains energy from being applied to a human brain. Have you ruled such options out?

Comment: It will also have to block at the 3rd harmonic. Even harmonics, and higher odd harmonics will not be expected to be as strong as the fundamental and third harmonic, but they might require attenuation depending on your specifications.

Comment: the application is about injecting analog audio over your own domestic power line. the provider's electric meter should be provided with enough filters so to prevent transmission out to the distribution grid, depending on location; in my own setup i added an additional EMI filter just after the electric meter in order to comply with possible regulations on QRM noise sources escaping the private spaces.

Comment: wireless is not an option because 1) there is no carrier or modulation needed , since the broadcasted spectrum should be the audible band 2) it wouldn't be easily contained within the private spaces, so to possibly infringe some regulations 3) it is not feasible to transmit over the air such audible band (ELF-VLF-LF) without infringing regulations, and without requiring high power.

Comment: the application is based on very low power signal distributed via domestic AC wiring, that despite reasonable criticisms about power being not enough to have sensible effects, it actually works - assuming some subjective conditions - by means of sort of sub-liminal/extrasensory perception that proved to have beneficial effects in specific conditions

Comment: Your transmitter will need an extremely low output impedance. The buzz (many harmonic frequencies) from light dimmers and motor speed controllers will cause your idea to fail. Do it properly with a carrier with a frequency away from the interference..